# Question on the way to look for convergency

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I wanted to find when the the series $\sum_n \left( \frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{n^{x/2}}\right)x^n$ converges (consider $x>0$). I applyed the root test, finding that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x\left(\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{n^{x/2}} \right)^{1/n}=0 \ \forall x$  Thus I concluded that the series was always convergent, which is false, in fact the series converges only if $0<x<1$. One thing I noticed is that I didn't check for $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$, which is true only when $x<1$ (and thus this allows me to get the correct result). Should I do this kind of checks whenever I deal with a series whose general term is x-dependent?

Answer (score 1):

> I applied the root test, finding that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x\left(\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{n^{x/2}} \right)^{1/n}=0 \ \forall x$

**This is the mistake here.** Using the ratio test would be fine, you just didn't compute the limit correctly: note that, for every $x>0$,
$$
x\left(\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{n^{x/2}} \right)^{1/n}
\geq x\left(\frac{1}{6^n}\right)^{1/n} = \frac{x}{6} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{x}{6} > 0
$$so the limit cannot be zero.
You also have
$$
x\left(\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{n^{x/2}} \right)^{1/n}
\geq x\left(\frac{1}{n^{x/2}}\right)^{1/n} = x e^{-\frac{x}{2}\frac{\ln n}{n}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} x > 0
$$
incidentally, which explains why the convergence will be for $x\in[0,1)$. (This requires a little bit more work (not much) to show it, but this at least shows that the series will diverge for $x>1$, by comparison and the ratio test).

Comment: It is divergent for $x=1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. I was so focused on the rest, I didn't even check that. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the first inequality you wrote, but could you show me how to evaluate the limit in the correct way using limit operations only?

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera You have lower bounds, showing divergence for $x>1$. To show convergence for $x < 1$ (i.e., use the ratio test then), you can use that $1/6^n + 1/n^{x/2} \leq 2/n^{x/2}$ for all large enough $n$ (and fixed $x$). [And, at the end, check the case of $x=1$ separately: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{6^n}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \infty$]

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two two terms. The second series $\sum \frac {x^{n}} {n^{x/2}}$ converges for $0<x<1$ and diverges for $x >1$ by Ratio Test. The first series converges for $0<x<1$ (also for $1 \leq x <6$ but that is immaterial). Hence, the given series converges for $0<x<1$ and diverges for $x>1$. Now check that the series diverges for $x=1$.

Comment: Am I always allowed to split the series in two terms?

Comment: Also, the first series converges when $x<6$

Comment: Yes, If $a_n,b_n >0$ then $\sum (a_n+b_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both converge. @GabrielePrivitera

Comment: While this is a good way to prove the result, this answer fails to point out what the OP's mistake is -- i.e., there is no conceptual error in their approach: there is just a mistake in computing the limit.

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera You want both the series to converge so the converges of the first one for $x$ between $1$ and $6$ is immaterial.

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera In such problems you are strongly advised to split it into two series.  That makes the analysis simpler.

Comment: I agree with that -- both series are non-negative, so this is by far the simplest and nicest way to proceed. (But, again, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the ratio test here. The issue was in the computation.)

Comment: Ok thank you so much to the both of you!